# Why do other people get a 404 on my website? (Using PHP on it)

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, web

So I have access to a hosting on a /www folder on my school's domain name, the problem is that only people on the school's network are able to reach that folder (which shouldn't happening, unless they have it restricted to VPN access only).

If that's the case, how would I go about modifying my .htaccess file to let outsiders access m y site or disable the VPN requirement? I remember fiddling with my htaccess file, that may have broke it but I dunno what happened. . . Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this could be used by the `.htaccess`. Look at the settings for any firewall or proxy along the way.

Comment: @JanDvorak - The settings of . . ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the restriction was originally in the .htaccess file, you will not be able to add outside access directly.

Requiring VPN access is something that is done on a network-level (not a folder or user level, which is what you are trying to do).  This means you would have to ask the administrator to do this for you.  I doubt you'll have access to modifying any firewall, proxy, or routing tables the school has set in place.  Also, doing so may be illegal.

For a quick work-around, if you have access to a public folder, you can try adding symlink to your www directory.  This is unlikely to work as (a) I doubt you have access to a public directory, and (b) schools usually disable `FollowSymLinks` in Apache

Comment: I actually do have access to a public directory and I can define my own .htaccess file if necessary. They have options for using .htaccess so you can password protect your files or require a login so only University students can get the files. . . So what should I add to my .htaccess file? I know nothing about Apache.

Comment: just add a symlink into the public directory.  And then try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` into the .htaccess of the public directory.  And without seeing your university's specific setup, I can't help you much more.

Comment: I think I may actually have access to it . . .

https://gist.github.com/9c8fd5db9b283bc5b6fd -> Gist of /etc/httpd/http.conf.orig